# What is meant by $|dxdy|^{1/2}$ in the integral?

Tags: integration, operator-theory

In this [Daniel Grieser - Basics of the b-calculus](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010314) paper the author mentions the term of a half-density on page 54 as *an object which look like $u(x) |dx_1 \cdots dx_n|^{\frac{1}{2}}$*. And I'm not aware of what this object should be.

I would appreciate any kind of help and/or sources for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

He simply means a quantity which changes as the expression written would under changes of coordinate, I believe. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_field for definitions of **tensor densities**.

In particular, just as the volume form changes with the determinant of the Jacobian matrix, he wants a quantity which changes with its square root. The prototypical example is the square root of the determinant of a metric in GR.

Comment: And how would this expression change under changes of coordinates? I'm sorry if this is fundamental, but I'm not very familiar with analysis this deep.

We had the projective coordinates: $x = x$ and $s = y/x$. So how would the written object change under the change of coordinates to those above?

Comment: $x=x,y=sx$ gives $dx\wedge dy= dx\wedge (sdx+xds)=x dx\wedge ds$ so it should get multiplied by $\sqrt x$, assuming I understand correctly. You can calculate $x$ as the determinant of a Jacobian.

Comment: What does the symbol $\wedge$ mean and thus $dx \wedge dy$?

Comment: This is the wedge product defined for differential forms. If you are not familiar with this notation yet, then just use the standard formula for the determinant of a matrix of partial derivatives (Jacobian) like I suggested previously!